# PyOdbc does not see the installed driver, how to make "Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb, * .accdb)" visible to Python?

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I wrote a Python test script that should read data from the Microsoft Access database, but I get an error message.

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\serge\PycharmProjects\TestPyOdbc\CustomerGasketData.mdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from dichtungen')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Error message:

```
C:\Users\serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:/Users/serge/PycharmProjects/TestPyOdbc/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/serge/PycharmProjects/TestPyOdbc/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\serge\PycharmProjects\TestPyOdbc\CustomerGasketData.mdb;')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked which ODBC drivers are available at all in Python:

[image]

there is no Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb, * .accdb) in this list, but the drivers are installed on the PC.

[image]

What do I need to do to make Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb, * .accdb) available in Python?

Comment: It's cause 2 listed there, either run Python in 32-bit mode, or install the 64-bit ODBC driver

Comment: I have MS Office 32bit, after installing Python 3.8.10-32, the driver problem has been resolved!